# how to transform the js slide arrow into html markup

Tags: javascript, html, css

h1, I got design something like below which is one slider show, center mode slider, with the arrows placed between next and prev slide.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AvSTD.png)

I found this good source (https://codepen.io/haileyang/pen/jOVxYxN) for my work.

Since the width of slides is responsively modifying, however, it is hard to locate the arrow always between beside slides. I
wonder if is there any way to control those arrows as I am thinking if there are ways to position relative to only the center slider for prev and next button or if there are ways to replace that js button into written HTML so that I can use max-width and display flex to little close to what I want.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.slick-carousel').slick({
    centerMode: true,
    centerPadding: '67px',
    slidesToShow: 1,
    responsive: [{
      breakpoint: 768,
      settings: {
        arrows: true,
        centerMode: true,
        centerPadding: '45px',
        slidesToShow: 1
      }
    }, {
      breakpoint: 480,
      settings: {
        arrows: true,
        centerMode: true,
        centerPadding: '45px',
        slidesToShow: 1
      }
    }]
  }); // $('.slick-carousel')
  
    $('.slick-item').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var activity = $(this);
    var title = activity.find('h3').text();
    var desc = activity.find('p').text();
    var img = activity.find('a').attr('href');
    var html = '<div class="modal fade lightbox-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel">';
    html += '<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">';
    html += '<div class="modal-content">';
    html += '<div class="modal-body">';
    html += '<div class="caption">';
    html += '<div class="caption-content">';
    html += '<h3>' + title + '</h3>';
    html += '</div>';
    html += '</div>';
    html += '<img src="' + img + '" alt="" class="img-responsive">';
    html += '<p>' + desc + '</p>';
    html += '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>';
    html += '</div>';
    html += '</div>';
    html += '</div>';
    html += '</div>';
    $("body").append(html);
    $(".lightbox-modal").modal().on("hidden.bs.modal", function() {
      $(this).remove()
    })
    return false;
  });
  
}); // (function)
```

```css
body {
  padding: 30px 0;
}

/*!*
* Slick Custom Theme
*/
.slick-carousel .slick-item {
  color: white;
  background-color: #3498db;
  min-height: 250px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin: 0 15px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.slick-carousel .slick-item:hover {
  opacity: .7
}

.slick-prev:before,
.slick-next:before {
  color: black;
  content: '';
}

.slick-arrow {
  width: 55px;
  height: 55px;
  z-index: 5;
  border-top: 3px solid #06d1a4;
  border-right: 3px solid #06d1a4;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-out;
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease-out;
}

.slick-arrow:hover {
  opacity: .5
}

.slick-prev {
  left: 0%;  
  transform: rotate(225deg);
}

.slick-next {
  right: 0%;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}


/**!
* Caption Styles
*/

.caption-item {  
  right: 0;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.caption-link {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 400px;
}

.caption-link .caption-layer {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all ease .5s;
  -moz-transition: all ease .5s;
  transition: all ease .5s;
}

.caption-layer.green {
  background: rgba(173, 219, 50, .5);
}

.caption-layer.light-green {
  background: rgba(6, 209, 164, .7);
}

.caption-layer.blue {
  background: rgba(152, 231, 254, .5);
}

.caption-link .caption-layer:hover,
.caption-layer.video-icon {
  opacity: 1;
}

.caption-link .caption-layer .caption-content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 35%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: #fff;
}

.caption-link .caption-layer .caption-content p {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="container text-center">
      <h2>Slick Slider: <br> Create your custom theme</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
      <div class="slick-carousel">
        <div class="slick-item">
          <a href="http://lorempixel.com/960/250/food/1/" class="caption-link">
            <div class="caption-layer light-green">
              <div class="caption-content">
                <h3>SALAD</h3>
                <p class="hidden">Explore some of the World’s Best Snorkel Sites!An easy way to enjoy the underwater beauty that surrounds Ambergris Caye is to go snorkeling. All you need is a mask, snorkel, and fins. People of all ages and experience levels will take
                  home wonderful memories about their time in the water with us. Just in front of our resort on a quick kayak ride you can enjoy on of the best snorkeling site, Mexico Rocks.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/270/250/food/1/" alt="Image" class="img-responsive">
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="slick-item">
          <a href="http://lorempixel.com/960/250/food/2/" class="caption-link">
            <div class="caption-layer light-green">
              <div class="caption-content">
                <h3>POTATO</h3>
                <p class="hidden">Explore some of the World’s Best Snorkel Sites!An easy way to enjoy the underwater beauty that surrounds Ambergris Caye is to go snorkeling. All you need is a mask, snorkel, and fins. People of all ages and experience levels will take
                  home wonderful memories about their time in the water with us. Just in front of our resort on a quick kayak ride you can enjoy on of the best snorkeling site, Mexico Rocks.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/270/250/food/2/" alt="Image" class="img-responsive">
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="slick-item">
          <a href="http://lorempixel.com/270/250/food/3/" class="caption-link">
            <div class="caption-layer light-green">
              <div class="caption-content">
                <h3>SNORKELING</h3>
                <p class="hidden">Explore some of the World’s Best Snorkel Sites!An easy way to enjoy the underwater beauty that surrounds Ambergris Caye is to go snorkeling. All you need is a mask, snorkel, and fins. People of all ages and experience levels will take
                  home wonderful memories about their time in the water with us. Just in front of our resort on a quick kayak ride you can enjoy on of the best snorkeling site, Mexico Rocks.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/270/250/food/3/" alt="Image" class="img-responsive">
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="slick-item">
                    <a href="http://lorempixel.com/960/250/food/4/" class="caption-link">
            <div class="caption-layer light-green">
              <div class="caption-content">
                <h3>SALAD</h3>
                <p class="hidden">Explore some of the World’s Best Snorkel Sites!An easy way to enjoy the underwater beauty that surrounds Ambergris Caye is to go snorkeling. All you need is a mask, snorkel, and fins. People of all ages and experience levels will take
                  home wonderful memories about their time in the water with us. Just in front of our resort on a quick kayak ride you can enjoy on of the best snorkeling site, Mexico Rocks.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/270/250/food/4/" alt="Image" class="img-responsive">
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="slick-item">
                    <a href="http://lorempixel.com/960/250/food/5/" class="caption-link">
            <div class="caption-layer light-green">
              <div class="caption-content">
                <h3>SALAD</h3>
                <p class="hidden">Explore some of the World’s Best Snorkel Sites!An easy way to enjoy the underwater beauty that surrounds Ambergris Caye is to go snorkeling. All you need is a mask, snorkel, and fins. People of all ages and experience levels will take
                  home wonderful memories about their time in the water with us. Just in front of our resort on a quick kayak ride you can enjoy on of the best snorkeling site, Mexico Rocks.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/270/250/food/5/" alt="Image" class="img-responsive">
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="slick-item">
                    <a href="http://lorempixel.com/960/250/food/6/" class="caption-link">
            <div class="caption-layer light-green">
              <div class="caption-content">
                <h3>SALAD</h3>
                <p class="hidden">Explore some of the World’s Best Snorkel Sites!An easy way to enjoy the underwater beauty that surrounds Ambergris Caye is to go snorkeling. All you need is a mask, snorkel, and fins. People of all ages and experience levels will take
                  home wonderful memories about their time in the water with us. Just in front of our resort on a quick kayak ride you can enjoy on of the best snorkeling site, Mexico Rocks.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/270/250/food/6/" alt="Image" class="img-responsive">
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="slick-item">
                    <a href="http://lorempixel.com/960/250/food/7/" class="caption-link">
            <div class="caption-layer light-green">
              <div class="caption-content">
                <h3>SALAD</h3>
                <p class="hidden">Explore some of the World’s Best Snorkel Sites!An easy way to enjoy the underwater beauty that surrounds Ambergris Caye is to go snorkeling. All you need is a mask, snorkel, and fins. People of all ages and experience levels will take
                  home wonderful memories about their time in the water with us. Just in front of our resort on a quick kayak ride you can enjoy on of the best snorkeling site, Mexico Rocks.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/270/250/food/7/" alt="Image" class="img-responsive">
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="slick-item">
                    <a href="http://lorempixel.com/960/250/food/8/" class="caption-link">
            <div class="caption-layer light-green">
              <div class="caption-content">
                <h3>FRUIT</h3>
                <p class="hidden">Explore some of the World’s Best Snorkel Sites!An easy way to enjoy the underwater beauty that surrounds Ambergris Caye is to go snorkeling. All you need is a mask, snorkel, and fins. People of all ages and experience levels will take
                  home wonderful memories about their time in the water with us. Just in front of our resort on a quick kayak ride you can enjoy on of the best snorkeling site, Mexico Rocks.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/270/250/food/8/" alt="Image" class="img-responsive">
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom `navigation` arrow in `HTML` like below

**HTML**

Put this html is outside of your slider

```
<ul class="custom-nav">
        <li class="arrow prev"></li>
        <li class="arrow next"></li>
</ul>
```

**JS**

```
$('.slick-carousel').slick({
  prevArrow: $('.prev'), //add custom class
  nextArrow: $('.next'), //add custom class
});
```